# A variation on pinned equivalence relations

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, forcing, descriptive-set-theory

Recall (see e.g. [Zapletal, *Pinned equivalence relations*](https://people.clas.ufl.edu/zapletal/files/f2note.pdf)) that a Borel equivalence relation $E$ on $\omega^\omega$ is **pinned** iff for every forcing $\mathbb{P}$ and every $\mathbb{P}$-name $\nu$ we have $$\Vdash_{\mathbb{P}^2}\nu[G_0]E\nu[G_1]\quad\implies\quad\Vdash_\mathbb{P}  \exists r\in(\omega^\omega)^V(\nu[G]Er).$$ The Borel-ness of $E$ means that we don't have to worry about any strangeness around interpreting $E$ in generic extensions.

I'm curious what happens if we allow some flexibility in the "$\exists r\in(\omega^\omega)^V$"-clause of the conclusion. Specifically, what if we look not just at the ground model's reals but also all reals living in some "tame" forcing extension of the universe?

> **Definition**: For a class $\Gamma$ of forcing notions, say that a Borel equivalence relation $E$ on $\omega^\omega$ is *pinned-over-$\Gamma$* iff for every forcing $\mathbb{P}$ and every $\mathbb{P}$-name $\nu$ we have $$\Vdash_{\mathbb{P}^2}\nu[G_0]E\nu[G_1]\quad\implies\quad  \exists\mathbb{Q}\in\Gamma,\mu\in V^\mathbb{Q}(\Vdash_{\mathbb{P}\times\Gamma}\nu[G_0]E\mu[G_1]).$$

To motivate this, note that the usual example of a non-pinned Borel equivalence relation $F_2$ is also non-pinned-over-c.c.c., as is the Borel equivalence relation constructed in Zapletal's above-linked paper.

> **Question**: Is there a Borel equivalence relation which is unpinned but *is* pinned-over-c.c.c.?

I would also be interested in the analogue of this question with "projective" in place of "Borel;" here, however, we would need to also assume an appropriate large cardinal hypothesis (namely projective absoluteness) in order for things to even make sense at the outset.

Comment: With MA, can't you make pinned-over-c.c.c pinned?

Comment: @Otto I don't immediately see how; can you elaborate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Larson & Zapletal, *Geometric Set Theory*](https://bookstore.ams.org/view?ProductCode=SURV/248):

> Definition 2.6.1. A poset $P$ is *reasonable* if for every ordinal $\lambda$ and for every function $f:\lambda^{<\omega}\to\lambda$ in the $P$-extension there is a set $a\subset\lambda$ which is closed under $f$, belongs to the ground model, and is countable in the ground model. 
>
> In particular, all c.c.c. and all proper forcings are reasonable. Good examples of unreasonable forcings are posets which collapse $\aleph_1$, Namba forcing and Prikry forcing. 
>
> Theorem 2.6.2. Let $E$ be an analytic equivalence relation on a Polish space $X$. If $P$ is a reasonable forcing and $\tau$ is an $E$-pinned name on $P$, then $\tau$ is trivial.

In the notation of the original question, $\mu$ is $E$-pinned on the ccc forcing $\mathbb{Q}$, so the above theorem implies that $\mu$ is trivial. Then it follows that $\nu$ is trivial and so $E$ is pinned.

To provide more context:

> Corollary 2.6.6. Let $E$ be an analytic equivalence relation on a Polish space $X$, Borel reducible to an orbit equivalence relation. If $E$ is not pinned then the following are equivalent for any partial order $P$:
> (1) $P$ carries a nontrivial $E$-pinned name;
> (2) $P$ collapses $\aleph_1$ to $\aleph_0$.